# In Unity, how do I see the details of a given launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I have a few launchers in Unity that I might want to run as sudo once or twice, but I have no idea what to type into the terminal.

At the moment, crazily, I have to run the app, then search for likely candidates in System Monitor! I don't think the Unity Design team intend, ever, to give us a right-click action on the Dash, or a "Details" option if I right-click on a Launcher, so... how do I figure out what's actually being executed when I run a Launcher?

(for the curious, what I'm struggling with is Desura - it's not in the system path, so I can't just `whereis desura`, assuming `desura` is what's actually being run - I'd be guessing)

[EDIT : using the method I marked as the answer, I can see that Desura installs in my home directory and as it's a non-root install, it doesn't update the system path.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the contents of the launcher file you can open gedit and drag&drop a launcher icon from the dash into it.

Gedit will then display the .desktop file for that launcher which is by the way stored in

```
/usr/share/applications
```

in my case for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Desura
GenericName=Game Manager
Comment=Download and play the best games
Exec=/home/daniel/desura/desura %U
TryExec=/home/daniel/desura/bin/desura
Path=/home/daniel/desura
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/desura;
Icon=/home/daniel/desura/data/desura.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;
StartupNotify=false
```

Now just look at the 'Exec=' line in that document in my case

```
Exec=/home/daniel/desura/desura %U
```

This will point you to where the executable is stored and tell you the name (desura).

By the way...normally it is neither necessary nor a good idea to run desura in root mode.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks! Still wish they'd add a right-click menu though... :-)

Comment: Oh, and tried to run Desura as root to fix an issue and you're right - it doesn't want to do that. Found another way around the issue though, so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the starter file properties

Drag the icon onto the desktop, right click on it and select "Proprerties". The command is in the "Command" field:

[image]

### Use Arronax

Install [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/), open Arronax and drag the icon from the dash into Arronax. , the command is in the "Command" field:

[image]

Comment: Hadn't come across Arronax before, thanks. I tried to install Alacarte, but it wanted a pile of dependencies!